# Poisson distribution for indicator function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

Let $N_t:=\mathbb{I}_{(t\leq \tau \leq T)}$ a counting process with Poisson distribution. I know that $X\sim \mathrm{Po} \Rightarrow P(X=k):=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!}$.

Assuming that $\lambda:=\int_{t}^{s}\lambda_udu$.

> **Why $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r_sds}\mathbb{I}_{(t\leq \tau\leq T)}]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[\int_{t}^{T}e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r_sds}\lambda(s)e^{-\int_{0}^{s}\lambda_udu}]$**?

I've only understood (trivially) that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x)dx\rightarrow \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[\int_{t}^{T}...]$.

Comment: What is $E^Q$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is only a notation to indicate the risk-neutral measure. But this is a purely financial notation, and this changes nothing in terms of the proof. Let $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{E}$.